# extra value not passed from activity using onActivityResult to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**Update** 
**Activity A** ==> host **MyFragment** and from here,user started ==> **ActivityB** from here I need to get some value from this activty for example value integer and some String to **MyFragment** that hosted in **ActivityA**

I've **MyFragment** that start the **activityB** like this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),NewsCommentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("MNewsFeed", new Gson().toJson(newsFeed));
        intent.putExtra("idCommentBadge",idCommentBadge);
        startActivityForResult(intent,addComment);
```

and then when user start the activty and finish it I'm trying to pass some value from that **ActivityB** to **MyFragment** like this  :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //set ok result before finish the activity

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("idBadgeComment", idBadgeComment);
        returnIntent.putExtra("totalCommentInserted", totalCommentInserted);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

and I've implement onActivityResult in **MyFragment** :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i(TAG, "Result from News Comment ");

        if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Log.i(TAG, "Result from News OK");
            if(requestCode==addComment){
                Log.i(TAG, "Result ReqCode Oke");

                int idBadgeComment = data.getExtras().getInt("idBadgeComment");
                int totalCommentInserted = data.getExtras().getInt("totalCommentInserted");

                Log.i(TAG, "idComment: "+idBadgeComment);
                Log.i(TAG, "Total Comment Inserted: "+totalCommentInserted);
            }
        }
    }
```

also I've called onActivityResult in **ActivityA** that hosted **MyFragment** :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        /**
         * call below code to get the result on the fragment
         */
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewpager);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

when I try the code above I only get `Log.i(TAG, "Result from News Comment ");` and it didn't get the `RESULT_OK` value and the **Intent data** is null, can someone please pointed out where did I go wrong? and how to pass the value from activity to fragment ? or maybe a better way instead of using onActivityResult?

Comment: You start fragment from your activity. So you have a reference to that fragment. Why do you need additional methods (like onActivityResult) to pass some values to that fragment? You can just create method in your fragment setXYZ(XYZ xyz) and call that from activity.

Comment: yes I can do that for set the value, but I need to change something the UI  at mainUI Thread so I need taht value pass from the activity to my fragment

Comment: Activities run on UI thread. Change that from activity then.

Comment: @Wukash Your suggestion will not achieve what I wanted in this case

Comment: @Wukash wouldn't that be different UI thread? cuz when I'm starting the activity from the fragment, from what I understand the activity that hosted the fragment will get onPause state or stop, I can't change the UI in from activity A in Activity B right?

Comment: super.onBackPressed(); remove this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try putting `super.onBackPressed();` as the last line since `RESULT_CANCELED` is returned on back press.

Answer (score 0):

Just startActivity by activity.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),NewsCommentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("MNewsFeed", new Gson().toJson(newsFeed));
    intent.putExtra("idCommentBadge",idCommentBadge);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,addComment);
```

Or put your onActivityResult to fragment.

Comment: Yes I've tried to use getActivity() to startActivityForResult() in my fragment, but I still dont get the value from ActivitB is not passed trough. please see my update question thanks

Comment: and using getActivity() makes the Log.i(TAG, "Result from News Comment ");  is not printed in the fragment

Comment: @GujaratSantana remove super.onBackPress(). This line will finish the Activity.